# How to handle the Authentication dialog box of Firefox in mac using Selenium?

Tags: authentication

I am using the following app created with applescript to handle the authorization credentials in Firefox

```
on run ARGV
    delay 10
    tell application "plugin-container"
        activate
    end tell

    tell application "System Events"
        if UI elements enabled then
            tell process "Firefox"
                set frontmost to true
            end tell

            if length of ARGV < 2 then
                display dialog "Usage: FileName UserName Password"
                return
            end if

            keystroke item 1 of ARGV
            keystroke tab
            keystroke item 2 of ARGV
            keystroke return


        else
            tell application "System Preferences"
                activate
                set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
                display dialog "UI element scripting is not enabled. Check \"Enable access for assistive devices\""
            end tell
        end if
    end tell
end run
```

And using the following selenium code to invoke the app in my selenium code

```
    String[] dialog =  new String[]{ "src/test/resources/AuthenticationFF.app","UserName","Password" };
    //First String in the application name. Must be in your project folder. 
    // Second is UserName to log in 
    // Third is Password.
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(dialog);
```

The problem is, I am getting the following error when trying to access the app:

Cannot run program "src/test/resources/FF.app": error=13, Permission denied

Please advise. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the permission denied error by changing the app path to **src/test/resources/AuthenticationFF.app/Contents/MacOS/applet**, now I have to revisit the applescript since it is not inserting the user + password on the authentication box.